# Parse.com emails in other languages

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Parse.com allows you to send emails for resetting your password and to also to verify your email address. How do we send these same emails in other languages? I dont see any option to customize the content on the Parse 'Email Settings' option

Comment: Parse does not currently offer localization for these emails.  Unfortunately the only workaround is to build this functionality yourself.  It can be done with cloud code, afterSave methods and another column, one of the email modules..